# Understanding state and props changes with rerendering in react components

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a component which isn't re-rendering as I'd expect. I'm less concerned about this specific example than having a better understanding about how state, props, updates, re-rendering and more happens in the react-redux lifecycle.

My current code is about creating a delivery with a list of locations. The main issue is that reordering the location's itinerary doesn't seem to work - the state updates in the reducer correctly, but the components are not rerendering.

This is the relevant snippet from delivery.js, a component which uses the LocationSearch custom component to display each location in the list of locations:

```
{console.log("Rendering...")}
{console.log(delivery.locations)}
{delivery.locations.map((location, index) => (
    <div key={index}>
        <LocationSearch
            {...location}
            total={delivery.locations.length+1}
            index={index}
        />
    </div>
))}
```

The console.logs print out the correct data where and when expected. When an action to reorder the locations is triggered (from within LocationSearch), the console log prints out the list of locations with the data updated correctly. However the component is not displaying anything updated.

Here is some relevant parts of the LocationSearch component:

```
export class LocationSearch extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            searchText: this.props.address
        }
        this.handleUpdateInput = this.handleUpdateInput.bind(this)
    }

    handleUpdateInput (searchText) {
        this.setState({
            searchText: searchText
        })
        this.props.handleUpdateInput(searchText)
    }

    render(){
        const { type, itineraryOrder, floors, elevator, accessDistance, index} = this.props
        return (
            ...display all the stuff
        )
    }
}
...map dispatch, connect, etc...
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    return {
        suggestions: state.delivery.suggestions,
        data: ownProps.data
    };
}
```

This is where I get confused - I figure I'm meant to do something along the lines of `componentWillUpdate`, but can't find any good explanations for what happens at each step. Do I just set `this.props = nextProps` in there? Shouldn't this.props have updated already from the parent component passing them in? How come most components seem to rerender by themselves?

Any help you can give or links to good resources I'd be grateful for. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I kept running into this kind of issues right before I discovered redux. Considering you mentioned already using react-redux, maybe what you should do is switch to a container/component structure and forget about componentWillUpdate()

Basically, what this allows for is just passing fresh props to the components that renders the actual HTML, so you don't have to replace the props by hand.

Your container could be something like this

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import PresentationalComponent from 'components/PresentationalComponent'

const Container = props => <PresentationalComponent {...props} />

export default connect( state => ({
    searchText: state.UI.searchText,
    locations: [...],
}), dispatch => ({
    handleUpdateInput: e => dispatch( {
        type: "CHANGE_SEARCH_TEXT",
        text: e.target.value,
    } ),
}))(Container)
```

And your presentational component

```
import React from 'react'

const PresentationalComponent = ({ searchText, locations, handleUpdateInput }) => 
<div>
    {locations.map(location => <p>{location}</p>)}
    <input defaultValue={searchText} type="text" onChange={handleUpdateInput} />
</div>

export default PresentationalComponent
```